# Objective C - How to use extern variables?

Tags: objective-c, global-variables, extern

I am trying to use extern variables.

It complains that because of using numberWithInt I am not passing a contants as the value of my variable

So I removed the const and it's complaining that an extern variable must be a constant, so what is the solutions here?

**I DO NOT WANT TO USE INT**

```
.h
extern NSNumber const *MoveID;

.m
NSNumber const *MoveID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try to do the following:

.h

```
extern NSNumber *MoveID;
```

.m

```
NSNumber *MoveID;
@implementation MYGreatClass
+ (void) initialize {
    static bool done = FALSE;
    if(!done){ // This method will be called again if you subclass the class and don't define a initialize method for the subclass
        MoveID = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] retain];
        done = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the value of `MoveID` isn't gonna be set until something somewhere touches the `MYGreatClass` class.  You *could* use a `+load` method if that is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

As @BoltClock said, you cannot set a non-constant value to be of `const` type.

What you *could* do is this:

```
extern NSNumber *MoveID;
```

And...

```
NSNumber *MoveID;
@implementation SomeClass 
static BOOL loaded = NO;
+ (void) initialize {
   if(!loaded) {
      MoveID = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];
      loaded = YES;
   }
}
//blah blah blah

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I just realized that I totally missed the question and was going on about why the error was occurring, oops. I'll leave the first part of my answer here though because Jacob Relkin quotes it in his answer.

---

Because `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]` is not a compile-time constant value, you cannot set an `NSNumber` created with it to a `const` variable.

<del>There appears to be a [radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/6406062) about `extern NSNumber const`s, which seem to be unsupported in Objective-C. I guess you can use a preprocessor macro to create `NSNumber`s from constant ints or floats as described [in this article](http://www.extinguishedscholar.com/wpglob/?p=346). It's not nearly the same as what you intend but it seems to be pretty close.</del>

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, the modern method is do do it as:

in .h

```
extern NSNumber *MoveID;
```

in .m

```
NSNumber *MoveID;

...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        MoveID = @1;
    });

    ...
}
```

`dispatch_once()` will only ever run once so the initialiser is not duplicated, and it is thread safe. Also, pushing down initialisation code lower down in the view lifecycle.