# Why NSNumber literals cannot be used in static declarations

Tags: objective-c, ios, static, ios6, nsnumber

I'm declaring:

```
static NSString *a = @"a";
```

and this is a correct declaration in iOS6 (it should be more correct to use the compiler version but I do not know it at the moment). I thought that with number literals also:

```
static NSNumber *b=@1;
```

could be a valid declaration. Compiler tells me that `initializer element is not a compile time constant`. This surprises me a bit. Since `NSNumber` is immutable as `NSString` and since I'm using a literal as in string case, I thought it could be valid as well.

Does anybody have a reasonable explanation about this difference?

Comment: I have also wondered this, and I can't think of any good reason one would work and not the other, other than historical. My guess is it's not a high priority to make it work.

Comment: Immutable and "compile time" are two different things.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first line is a compile-time constant since you are assigning `@"a"` and not something like `static NSString *a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a"];`(That will throw the same error)

But for an `NSNumber`, `static NSNumber *b = @1;` is actually equivalent to `static NSNumber *b = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];`. For more details [check Objective-C Literals.](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

Note that in the above case, the right side is not a compile-time constant. It is an expression that must be evaluated at runtime. In C and Objective-C, static variables must be initialized with compile-time constants.

If you want to have `NSNumber` as a `const` you can check with the approaches mentioned here [Objective C - How to use extern variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360327/objective-c-how-to-use-extern-variables).

Also [check this on Objective C literals from Mike Ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-06-22-objective-c-literals.html),

> It's important to note that none of the new literal syntax qualifies
>   as a compile-time constant.

And,

> NSString literals are also compile-time constants, because of a tight
>   coupling between the compiler and the libraries. There's a special
>   NSString subclass called NSConstantString with a fixed ivar layout:
>
> This tight coupling has advantages, like producing legal global
>   variable initializers, and requiring no extra code to run to build the
>   object at runtime. However, there are big disadvantages as well. The
>   NSConstantString layout is set forever. That class must be maintained
>   with exactly that data layout, because that data layout is baked into
>   thousands of third-party apps. If Apple changed the layout, those
>   third-party apps would break, because they contain NSConstantString
>   objects with the old layout.
>
> If NSArray literals were compile-time constants, there would need to
>   be a similar NSConstantArray class with a fixed layout that the
>   compiler could generate, and that would have to be maintained
>   separately from other NSArray implementations. Such code could not run
>   on older OSes which didn't have this NSConstantArray class. The same
>   problem exists for the other classes that the new literals can
>   produce.
>
> *This is particularly interesting in the case of NSNumber literals.
>   Lion introduced tagged pointers, which allow an NSNumber's contents to
>   be embedded directly in the pointer, eliminating the need for a
>   separate dynamically-allocated object. If the compiler emitted tagged
>   pointers, their format could never change, and compatibility with old
>   OS releases would be lost. If the compiler emitted constant NSNumber
>   objects, then NSNumber literals would be substantially different from
>   other NSNumbers, with a possible significant performance hit.*
>
> *Instead, the compiler simply emits calls into the framework,
>   constructing the objects exactly like you would have done manually.
>   This results in a bit of a runtime hit, but no worse than building
>   them yourself without the new syntax, and makes for a much cleaner
>   design.*

Comment: You are making this personal @vikingosegundo.

Comment: Weird, I figured `@"a"` was just sugar for something like `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"a"]`

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Ventura, this is no longer a problem, the following compiles fine.

```
NSArray *constant_nsarray_test=@[ @"string1", @(1) ];
```

It generates a .o file with empty text section and referencing the class `NSConstantArray` and `NSConstantIntegerNumber`, in addition to the constant string.

Linking against that file or loading it dynamically allows you to retrieve the array and access its contents.