# Use and Access Global/Extern Variables in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, global-variables

I know this question has been asked a billion times, but my particular question hasn't been answered. So sorry about the repetitiveness.

So I know how to declare and define extern variables (correct me if I'm wrong):

in foo.h file:

```
extern NSString *foo;
```

in foo.m file:

```
NSString *foo = @"fooey";
```

But then say I want to access/change the variable in the hoo.m file. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .h

```
 @interface SOViewController : UIViewController{
    NSString * variable;
 }
```

in .m you can set it wherever.

For example, viewDidLoad.

You can also declare this in the .m file by putting the declaration

```
@interface SOViewController(){
    NSString * variable;
}
  // @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * myString; might be appropriate here instead
@end
```

Before the @implementation.

Ideally, since this is object-oriented programming, though, best practice would be to make the string a property of the class.

If you are really set on the extern keyword here is a stackoverflow post on how to use it [Objective C - How to use extern variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360327/objective-c-how-to-use-extern-variables)

**EDIT**

The question came down to how to pass variables around.  You can look at this article [How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object) to see an example of how to do that with seguing.

Comment: Yes, that's how you define/declare it. But how do I access it in a different class besides foo.h/m?

Comment: Ah, I see.  You would need to pass it to that class.

Comment: Declare it as an external variable (.h) and then in prepareForSegue or when you declare the new viewController set a property in that viewController where you need it.

Comment: Ok, so set it as a property in a different viewController. Do you have a link for how to do that? Or you could put it in the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object is an example of how to do this with segues.